# Angular 5 : calling an api protected by 2 way ssl

Tags: angular, ssl

My use case is the Front end application should call an api which is protected by 2 way ssl.

I am new to angular and trying to find the answers for the below questions:

1. Is it possible to call an api protected by 2 way ssl from angular application?
2. How does the angular application pass the certificate to the api and how does it verify the certificate from the server?

Comment: Have you tried to call API ? Have you faced any issue ? If yes then add in question.

Comment: no.. i havent tried calling the api. i want to understand first if its possible to do so in angular using HttpClient, as i was not able to find any option to pass the client certificate in the call.

Comment: Till I have worked and see who are working or using ssl they just used the normal API call. So please try first and then let me know if you face any issue. :)